# Как при случайном сообщении бот мог ответить любым сообщением, который уже был в чате?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Вообщем. Надеюсь, я смогу обьяснить.
Человек отправил какое нибуть сообщение, например:
"Ща"

А бот смог брать любое сообщение из чата, скажем "я звезда" и отвечал ему:
"я звезда"

Вот пример на фотографии:
[image: пример лмпо]

У меня не так уж и много навыка в програмировании на Discord.Py, так что **любая** помощь мне поможет.

Comment: Делай БД или что то другое, куда ты будешь записывать все сообщения с чата, ну а потом, с тайм-аутом, отсилай в чат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покажу Вам очень костыльный вариант.


В моём варианте бот будет парсить последние `200` сообщений канала и отправлять рандомное. Число можно поставить любое, но если сообщение было отправлено больше 2х недель назад, то не факт что бот сможет его получить.

Ссылка на документацию -> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.history


Сам **код**:

```
import random

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    number_of_message = random.randint(0, 200) # Тут указываем лимит сообщений
    messages = await message.channel.history(limit=200).flatten() # Тут указываем лимит сообщений
    await message.channel.send(messages[number_of_message].content)
```